# How to set JVM version to run PlayFramework 1.2.x?

Tags: playframework, java-8, playframework-1.x

Recently I've moved my Play Framework 1.2.x project from Windows to OS x. I've also installed new Java 8 Environment - JRE and JDK.

So when I try to run my project, I catch an Exception. Google says it's because JDK 8 compiler have strange effect on Play Framework 1.2.x compilation.

So, if this possible, I would prefer to run this app using old version of JDK and JRE. Is this possible without reinstalling them?

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple shellscript to launch the play 1.2.7 framework:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
play-1.2.7/play $@
```